# Operator overloading in generic struct: can I create overloads for specific kinds(?) of generic?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I'm defining physical units in C#, using generic structs, and it was going okay until I got the error:

> One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

when trying to overload the mathematical operators so that they convert between different units. So, I have something like this:

```
public interface ScalarUnit { }
public class Duration : ScalarUnit { }

public struct Scalar<T> where T : ScalarUnit
{
    public readonly double Value;

    public Scalar(double Value)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(Scalar<T> Value)
    {
        return Value.Value;
    }
}

public interface VectorUnit { }
public class Displacement : VectorUnit { }
public class Velocity : VectorUnit { }

public struct Vector<T> where T : VectorUnit
{
    #...

    public static Vector<Velocity> operator /(Vector<Displacement> v1, Scalar<Duration> v2)
    {
        return new Vector<Velocity>(v1.Magnitude / v2, v1.Direction);
    }
}
```

There aren't any errors for the `+` and `-` operators, where I'm just working on a `Vector<T>`, but when I substitute a unit for `T`, suddenly it doesn't like it. Is there a way to make this work?

I figured it would work, since `Displacement` implements the `VectorUnit` interface, and I have `where T : VectorUnit` in the struct header. Am I at least on the right track here? I'm new to C# so I have difficulty understanding what's going on sometimes.

Comment: From the spec -"... a conversion operator must convert either to or from the class or struct type in which the operator is declared." As far as I know, there's no way to declare a user-defined operator *specifically* for a particular *constructed* generic type. That does seem quite weird anyway; it would be really unintuitive for users of your code. Surely you could find a better way to design this?

Comment: I didn't think dividing meters by seconds and getting back meters-per-second was weird. I'm merely trying to accomplish type-safety in some physics maths. Plus, I thought it'd be cool to write :) Oh and this is coming from my last design: duplicate tonnes and tonnes of code making a separate struct for every unit

Comment: Petition the language team for "extension operators". ;)

Comment: @Carson Myers: I think the goal of "type-safety in some physics maths" is great. What I meant by unintuitive is that what your design appears to want is for closing a generic type with a "magic" type-argument suddenly opening up a bunch new features not available with other (but perfectly valid) type arguments.

Comment: @Ani understandable, although it's not really a bunch of new features, it's just a different return type depending on the arguments. Unfortunately that effect seems to come with an unwieldly large amount of boilerplate code

Comment: @Carson Myers: Have you looked at the F# units of measure feature? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/08/29/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units.aspx

Comment: @Ani 8| ...that...is...awesome! maybe I just need to do math in F# instead

Comment: An alternate approach (which you may or may not have considered): define only base units (metres, seconds or whatever) but instead of constructors use static FromMiles(), FromChains(), etc. factories that convert. More precision is lost due to conversion factors rather than FPU rounding, so ignore that, and a consistent set of units makes calculations far simpler. Now you can define `MetresPerSecond Metres.operator /(Metres,Seconds)` but you don't have to worry about `operator /(Miles,Hour)` as well.

Comment: @Zooba I was only using metric units to begin with, but I have vector and scalar units, so I called them "speed" and "velocity", since they both have a unit of `m/s`. The problem is that dividing a meter by a second should give a meter per second, instead it won't work.

Comment: @Carson Myers: I see. I assumed you were going for polymorphic units. Since vectors have more components than scalars, there is no way to assign one to another and hence no way to break overloading. If you create classes for Speed, Velocity, Displacement, Distance, etc. you won't come out with any more code than using generics (probably less, and as a bonus, it will work, too!).

Comment: @Zooba I got about half way through making a class for each unit, and it was a lot more code than what I was doing with generics -- I had to re-write the constructor, implicit operators, comparison operators + and - operators (a couple times each), and then the appropriate * and / operators, for every single unit. Most of it was just duplicated code but it _had_ to all be separate or it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @Carson Myers: Ultimately, because speed/velocity/displacement/etc. are fundamentally different - not just different units, different quantities - I can't see that you have much choice. Following the pattern shown in your question you would be doing the same thing anyway. You may be able to simplify things by defining a general 'direction' value type and constructing vector quantities as their equivalent scalars and a direction value (rather than using orthogonal components). (Also, I suspect your generics pattern would work fine in C++ with templates, though probably not an easy transition.)

Comment: @Zooba right, it's ultimately the same thing -- but it was _much_ less code. Unfortunately it also doesn't work. I've decided that -- since it's a personal project -- I'd like to learn some F# and move the physics work into a separate F# library, so I won't really be fighting with this gigantic unit mess anymore anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think operators can be generic.

I would maybe consider hardcoding the types in the operator, i.e. if typeof(T).GetGenericParameters()[0] is this or that type blah blah.

Another approach whouch I would even prefer is implementing a common interface/base class in all the subclasses that returns a double, then, from the operator, you cast it down to that interface/b. class and get the values to calculate.

Note: by [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb.aspx), interface names should always start with `I` (example: `IScalarUnit`).

Comment: I tried just taking `Vector<T>` in the operator, but there are multiple overloads for `Vector<T>, Scalar<Duration>` and I can't differentiate them by the return type. Returning double from everything defeats the purpose for me a little bit, since you could multiply anything by anything and assign it to anything, since it would all be double inbetween the operations. And I know about `I`, but they're not _really_ an interface to anything, considering they're empty :P

Comment: @Maybe instead of returning double you can return the interface itself. regarding the `I`, it doesn't matter, it should **always** start with an upper `I`.

Comment: I was just kidding, they originally weren't interfaces, I just changed them to that to see if it would change anything